# Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken! No output read

Tags: python, apache-storm

I'm new to `python` and `storm` I tried to make `spout` read my data text file line by line but got this error

```
ERROR backtype.storm.util - Async loop died!
java.lang.RuntimeException: backtype.storm.multilang.NoOutputException: Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken! No output read.
Serializer Exception:
File "mspout.py", line 9
f = open('data.txt', 'r')
^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

the code is

```
def initialize(self, conf, context):
## Open the file with read only permit
f = open('data.txt', 'r')
```

Comment: Clearly your code is badly indented. As you can see, the line Python complains about sticks to the left, while other lines of the same function stay in the middle.

Comment: ohh thanks . i didn't notice that the spaces can make this . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line in question is missing an indentation.

Indentation in Python denotes where functions begin and end

> Python functions have no explicit begin or end, and no curly braces to mark where the function code starts and stops. The only delimiter is a colon (:) and the indentation of the code itself.

http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html

```
def initialize(self, conf, context):
## Open the file with read only permit
    f = open('data.txt', 'r')
```